# Need make wcf in silverlight application

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf, mvvm

I have application of silverlight.I'm building app by MVVM-pattern.For example, I have ViewModel with some methods that make some logic in my app, and I have some commands that use my methods with logic.
Some Method:

```
public void LoadImage(object param)
{
    bool result = (bool)_loadImage.ShowDialog();
    if (!result)
        return;
    ....
}
```

Command to this method:

```
public ICommand _LoadImage
{
    get{
        if (loadImage == null)
            loadImage = new Model.DelegateCommand(LoadImage, CanAdd);
        return loadImage;
    }
}
```

My goal is make WCF-service.I'm new in wcf and new even services
I'm creating WCF silverlight-application.
What I have to do next?Please provide me some examples or references wcf and mvvm in silverlight.
Where I should put my logic?I have replace it in svc?But how I will be use commands and bindig?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should learn the [basics of WCF services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734712.aspx) themselves.

The next step would be learning [how to consume a WCF service in Silverlight](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=228).

Comment: Thanks.I have read some basics already in troelsen.I just don't understand where I should put my logic methods, left it in viewmodel and call'em from service or replace on service(but I'm not sure) and call'em from view model some methods?

Comment: That's why I linked the second article which is especially about interaction between WCF and Silverlight.